# MKAnnotations not being added to mapview

Tags: objective-c, ios

For some reason the code below is not adding annotations to the map view. When I log out a count it returns 0, although it goes through the array almost 50 times. The Attraction object implements the MKAnnotation protocol.

```c
-(void)forwardGeocoderFoundLocation
{
int searchResults = [attractions count];
for(int i = 0; i < searchResults; i++){
    Attraction *a = [[Attraction alloc] init];
    a.address = [(Attraction *)[attractions objectAtIndex:i] address];
    a.city = [(Attraction *)[attractions objectAtIndex:i] city];
    a.state = [(Attraction *)[attractions objectAtIndex:i] state];

    NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@", a.address, a.city, a.state];

    NSString *theAddress = [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", theAddress];

    NSString *locationString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] usedEncoding:nil error:nil];

    //NSLog(@"%@", locationString);

    [[attractions objectAtIndex:i] setLocation:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:43.1330340 longitude:-77.6376329]];

    NSLog(@"Attraction location = %@", [[attractions objectAtIndex:i] location]);

    [self.mv addAnnotation:[self.attractions objectAtIndex:i]];

    NSLog(@"Mapview has %i annotations.", self.mv.annotations.count);

}

}
```

Here's the Attraction.h file:

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Attraction : NSObject<MKAnnotation>

@property(nonatomic,assign)int attractionID;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *address;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *description;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *city;
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *state;
@property(nonatomic,copy)CLLocation *location;

+ (id)attraction;
- (id)initWithID:(int)a_id name:(NSString *)a_name address:(NSString *)a_address description:(NSString*)a_description city:(NSString*)a_city state:(NSString *)a_state;

@end
```

And here's the Attraction.m file:

```cs
#import "Attraction.h"

@implementation Attraction

@synthesize attractionID, name, address, description, city, state, location;

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{
return self.location.coordinate;
}

- (NSString *)title{
return self.name;
}

- (NSString *)subtitle{
return self.name;
}

#pragma mark - 
+ (id)attraction {
return [[Attraction alloc] init ];
}

- (id)initWithID:(int)a_id name:(NSString *)a_name address:(NSString *)a_address description:(NSString*)a_description city:(NSString*)a_city state:(NSString *)a_state {

self = [super init];
self.attractionID = a_id;
self.address = a_address;
self.name = a_name;
self.description = a_description;
self.city = a_city;
self.state = a_state;

return self;

}

- (id)init
{
return [self initWithID:0 name:@"TBD" address:@"TBD" description:@"TBD" city:@"TBD"  state:@"TBD"];
}

@end
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is self.attractions the same as attractions? Are you sure self.mv is not nil?

Comment: Yeah self.attractions was the same as attractions, I changed it to see if it had any effect which it didn't. And I'm trying to figure it out, but it does look like self.mv is nil, and I'm not sure why. I hooked it up in the storyboard so I can't figure out why it would be nil.

Comment: I managed to figure it out. I had a protocol that was updating the attraction data for the map view, and in the method it was calling the forwardGeoocoderFoundLocation method, which was before viewDidLoad. I put the call to the method in viewDidLoad and it's working fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `self.mv` is `nil`, as you confirmed, then `self.mv.annotations.count` return `nil` (or 0, or something like that). And that is logged as 0 when you format it as `"%i"`.

But there is nothing in the code you submitted can cause it to be nil, so you must look for the reason in other parts of your code.

Comment: Thank you, the view was not loaded at the time I was calling the method to add the annotations to the map, so it was unable to. I found out what was wrong and it's working now!